# GroupBy causes Dump to omit linked objects in LinqPad to Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

I wired up my LinqPad to Entity Framework and was happily writing my query until I noticed that some of my objects were not in the result list.

I had a query that resembles this:

```
 IQueryable<IGrouping<Customer, Order>> myResults;
 myResults = Orders.Include("OrderDetail").GroupBy(x=>x.Customer);
 myResults.Dump(20);
```

When I ran that the Order.OrderDetail objects were not in the dump.  (The data is there though. I ran some foreach statements to check and it was all in the resulting objects, just not being dumped.)

But if I just run this:

```
 Orders.Include("OrderDetail").Dump(20);
```

Then I get the OrderDetail objects in the dump.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is it wrong to expect that LinqPad would dump my `Include` Objects even though there is a GroupBy going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572328/linq-when-using-groupby-include-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Seen something similar before. Did you try swapping the order of the groupby and include?

```
myResults = Orders.GroupBy(x=>x.Customer).Include("OrderDetail");
```

Comment: The `Include` method is not defined for the results of a `GroupBy`.  (It needs an `ObjectQuery` and `GroupBy` returns an `IQueryable`.)