# Linq when using GroupBy, Include is not working

Tags: linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

include matchparticipants is not working. It always says Null when I debug.
But when I put the GroupBy in comment it works fine. I am using Entity framework 4.3.1 with code-first.

Entities:

```
public class Match
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int MatchId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Matchtype is a required field")]
        public int Scheme { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool Finished { get; set; }

        public int Round { get; set; }


        // Relations
        [Required]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public Official Official { get; set; }

        public Slot Slot { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MatchParticipant> MatchParticipants { get; set; }
    }

 public class MatchParticipant
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int MatchParticipantId { get; set; }

        public int Points { get; set; }

        public int Goals { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Match Match { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Team Team { get; set; }
    }

public class Team
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is a required field")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Number of players is a required field")]
        public int NumberOfPlayers { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Coach is a required field")]
        public string Coach { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Phone is a required field")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string CellPhone { get; set; }

        public string Fax { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Email is a required field")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Address is a required field")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        public Pool Pool { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is a required field")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MatchParticipant> matchParticipants { get; set; }
    }

        var matches =
        context.matches
       .Include("Official")
       .Include("Slot")
       .Include("MatchParticipants.Team")
       .Include("Category.Tournament")
       .Where(m => m.Category.Tournament.TournamentId == tournamentId)
       .GroupBy(m => m.Category);
```

How can I make the Include work?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`Include` demands that the shape of the query doesn't change. It means that your query must return `IQueryable<Match>`. `GroupBy` operator is probably considered as shape changing because it returns `IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. Once the shape of the query changes all Include statements are omitted. Because of that you cannot use `Include` with projections, custom joins and groupings.

As a workaround you can execute grouping in Linq-to-objects:

```
var matches = context.matches
                     .Include("Official")
                     .Include("Slot")
                     .Include("MatchParticipants.Team")
                     .Include("Category.Tournament")
                     .Where(m => m.Category.Tournament.TournamentId == tournamentId)
                     .ToList()
                     .GroupBy(m => m.Category);
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in comments and in other answer, this is very dangerous workaround which can lead to performance problems. It pulls all records from database to the application and makes the aggregation in the app. It can work in same cases but it is definitely not applicable as generic solution.

Comment: Any further suggestions for when you have to keep your object type as an IQueryable<>?

Comment: This query is not optimized since it first get all rows from DB then "group by" in LINQ to Objects

Comment: @khosravi you are right. This is way to performance disaster. Shame on me that I ever proposed this solution without being very clear about that.

Answer (score 38):

In this special case, when your GroupBy is the latest operator, this query works good... But IMHO **answer above is the worst answer for beginer**, because it **causes really badly optimized query** when your GroupBy is not executed right after it, but is followed by some other statement (Where, Select...).

```
var ctx = new MyDataContext(); // Please use "using"
var result = ctx.SomeTable
                //.Include(ah => ah.IncludedTable) // DO NOT PUT IT HERE
                .Where(t => t.IsWhateverTrue)
                .GroupBy(t => t.MyGroupingKey)
                .Select(gt => 
                    gt.OrderByDescending(d => d.SomeProperty)
                        .FirstOrDefault(ah => ah.SomeAnotherFilter))
                .Include(ah => ah.IncludedTable) // YES, PUT IT HERE
                .ToList(); // Execute query here
```

Comment: This does not compile, IEnumerable<SomeTable> does not contain a definition for Include

Comment: Don't forget: using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: I can confirm that this approach works; i.e. putting the include at the end of the query.  Note that it might be necessary to add a Distinct prior to the include.

Comment: Wouldn't results contain only the first in each group in this case? How to include after group, so that ALL elements of the group remain in result?

Comment: For EF core, use `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: @KornelijePetak Enumerating the group item yields a sequence of all items in the group. So, `result` would contain the _last_ `SomeProperty` (or default) for each group because the items are sorted in descending order within the group.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work for me - getting InvalidOperationException - "Include has been used on non entity queryable"

Comment: You can't use this on projections.

Comment: @Tomino Well... There's a select statement there so that a projection. This solution does not seem to be working?

Comment: For the record: this query shape isn't supported in the current stable EF version (7.0.10).

Answer (score 3):

Specify the includes in the `.Select()`, after `GroupBy()`. This will include them in the result:

```cs
var result = ctx.SomeTable
                .Where(t => t.IsWhateverTrue)
                .GroupBy(t => t.MyGroupingKey)
                .Select(g => new
                  {
                    Date = g.Key.Value,
                    Reservations = g.Select(m => new
                        {
                          m,
                          m.IncludedTable // this selects/includes the related table
                        })
                  }
                );
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't find a working way to use Entity Framework to Group on the SQL side, and then Include() on the .net site. An alternative is to write your own SQL query and do your own mapping.
This actually isn't  that hard:

1. Run `Install-Package dapper` in the Nuget Package Manager Console for entity mapping
2. Define your custom object to map to (or use an existing one)

   ```
   class MyClass { int userID; int numRows;}
   ```
3. Query against your context object:

   ```
   List<MyClass> results = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().Query<MyClass>("SELECT u.id as userID, count(1) as numRows FROM Users u inner join Table2 t2 on u.id= t2.userID  group by u.id;").ToList();
   ```

Comment: *it appears you have to write your own code* -- That's not true. Even EF core, which largely dropped GroupBy support, supports GroupBy with aggregation.

Comment: Hi Gert. I probably should have said "if you want to join and aggregate" rather than "if you want to aggregate." As I don't thinking ef model binding does support joining and aggregating at the same time on the sql side. That's the whole point of Ladislav's answer above

Comment: No, the point is that the shape of the query changes. And then, they don't even want to aggregate, they want to `Include`, so it's all beside the point. Also, EF will also aggregate with a join query, why not?

Comment: Hi Gert. If you show me a code example which uses EF to perform a GroupBy operation on the SQL server side, and then calls Include() successfully, then I'll happily delete this answer. If not, then It seems to me that this answer may not deserve a downvote, as it could actually be helpful to people like me who land on this SO answer when trying achieve the same thing as I was.

Comment: It's simple. The question is not about aggregation. I don't understand why you bring it up here.

Comment: In a sense you're right. What's being discussed here is more aptly described as grouping rather than aggregation. I think it could be argued that grouping on any column actually means that you are aggregating on that column, as you're selecting the single key value from multiple rows with the same key. But all the same, I've edited the question to remove any usage of the word "aggregate." Hopefully this clarifies the answer a bit

Comment: Still has nothing to do with `Include`. Nothing in your solution builds an object graph. Tomino'a answer sufficiently shows how GroupBy and Include can be combined.

Comment: That's correct, It doesn't build an object graph. You have to define it in your DTO as I specified in step 2. If you think people would do better to look at Tomino's answer, then that's fine. I can't even get the query that he specified to execute at runtime, due to internal EF issues.

Comment: So at the risk of over-repeating myself here, what I'm offering is a way to group data on the SQL side, and return data from a joined table, without using EF core. This code is actually really useful because it means that you can do a straightforward db query in a performant and simple way without having to do constant battle with the internals of EF core.  Sure it doesn't facilitate Include() functionality. But it does facilitate the same thing that Include() is trying to achieve, without having to do battle with the internal workings of EF

Comment: Last comment. No. Include populates navigation properties. That's a huge difference.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the Include in the `.Select()` after `GroupBy()` like this:

```
var query = ctx.Table
   .Where(x => "condition")
   .GroupBy(g => g.GroupingKeyId)
   .Select(x => new
   {
       GroupingKeyId = x.Key.GroupingKeyId,
       GroupingKey = x.Select(y => y.GroupingKey)
            .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x.Key.GroupingKeyId)
   });
```

Comment: `x.Key.GroupingKeyId` is syntactically incorrect. And where's the `Include`? That said, I really don't think anything needs to be added to the existing answers.

Comment: @GertArnold `GroupingKey` here is a placeholder for the property being used for grouping and with reference to the question, `GroupingKeyId` could e.g. `MatchId` or `MatchParticipantId` while `GroupingKey` would be `Match` or `MatchParticipant`. Assigning `GroupingKey` this way automatically includes the property and where it is to be assigned to a collection like in @Benjamin's answer, you simply skip the `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I do LINQ for breakfast. Try an actual GroupBy with something like `g => g.GroupingKeyId` and you'll see what I mean. And again, where's `Include`?

Comment: I actually did that and it worked hence my answer.

Comment: No, it didn't. How can `Include` work if there's no `Include` in your code? Also, only `x.Key` is valid code. `x.Key.GroupingKeyId` would be valid if you'd group by  `g => new { g.GroupingKeyId }`.

Comment: This is my working code: 

`if (queryType == QueryType.Summary) 
{
      query = query.GroupBy(g => new { g.DataDate, g.HierarchyNodeId })
          .Select(x => new MetricData
          {
             DataDate = x.Key.DataDate,
             HierarchyNodeId = x.Key.HierarchyNodeId,
             HierarchyNode = x.Select(y => y.HierarchyNode).FirstOrDefault(y => y!.Id == x.Key.HierarchyNodeId), // include
             Created = _environmentService.CreateUtcDateTime()
          }); 
}`

Comment: That's not the code in the answer and still no Include. I give up.

Comment: That's my working code and it proves you wrong that `x.Key` is the only valid code. `g.HierarchyNodeId` is an implementation of `g.GroupingKeyId`. So yeah we should give up the back and forth. My code is working and "including" the virtual property I need.