# EF: How to group by multiple columns and include children of Key Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In EF query i want to group entity by 2 columns. and then  include the entity instance of grouped column

Below is generic repository. i have removed some code for brevity

```
  public class MyGenericRepository
  {
        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }
  }
```

Below i am grouping `PackageDetail` entity by `TemplateID` and `DocumentID` column. After grouping i am only interested in first ( Group Key) entity. I also want to include Key Entity's `Template` and `Document` child entity

```
IEnumerable<int> ids= GetIDs(); 

  var result = await _repository.GetQuery<PackageDetail>()
                .Include(x => x.Template)
                .Include(x => x.Document)
                .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ID))
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.TemplateID, x.DocumentID })
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToListAsync();
```

The code above correctly doing grouping and producing correct result. However resultant `PackageDetails` does not include `Template` or `Document` children.

Comment: Try Include after the Select. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572328/linq-when-using-groupby-include-is-not-working

Comment: @SteveGreene that worked