# Query running multiple times and is weirdly made

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Application Insights on my C# MVC web application. Going into End-to-end transaction details for a long running query.. I am getting that the following query runs over 10 times in a row on a slow page.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[paid] AS [paid]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [TableXX].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [TableXX].[paid] AS [paid]
    FROM [dbo].[TableXX] AS [TableXX]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

I'm not sure how to find it in my application. But also, I don't know why my TableXX is being subqueried with no where clause for the two fields if that makes sense.

Has anyone run into something like this? Could this be due to incorrectly using .Include, or just how EF structures certain type of Linq code smells?

Could this be it?

```
db.TableParent.Where(li => li.itemID == 16 && li.TableChild.TableXX != null && li.TableChild.companyId == company.id).ToList();
```

UPDATE:

So I used Database.Log and breakpoints to run my website locally and find the query that is causing the issue.

I create the following and pass it to a function that runs the second query below. Why is the ToList on the first one still letting the second one load them one by one?

```
List<TableParentItem> currentTableParentItems = db.TableParent.Where(i => i.id == givenId).Include(i => i.TableChild).Include(i => i.TableXX).GroupBy(i => new { i.id1, i.id2}).SelectMany(location => location.OrderByDescending(i => i.order).Take(1)).OrderBy(i => i.StartDate).ThenByDescending(i => i.id2).ToList();
```

..

```
result = currentTableParentItems.Where(i => i.Remaining > 0 && i.dueDate <= DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Where i.Remaining is a get { return TableXX.remaining; }

.. I'm also confused because when I set a breakpoint before and after the currentTableParentItems var above.. I get multiple queries: 1 into TableXX, 1 into TableParent, and 2 into TableChild... and then 5th one for a random table not referenced on that line..

Comment: I think is not posible because the expression within the Where clause is defined by the EntityType in this case TableParent, you should to use Include clause but you need to define the relation  between the parent and child entity in your context definition.

Comment: EF should execute only one query per linq. I think your best bet is to set a breakpoint in the Database.Log() method and look at the call stacks, or inspect the usual call stacks in the run of your application in general

Comment: Thank you for the help @DevilSuichiro. I used Database.Log and breakpoints to find where that query is being made. I updated my question above with a question about that query

Comment: @DevilSuichiro EF can execute more than one query per linq

@SweetTomato Yes I think it is running another query behind the scenes each time you check TableXX.remaining in the 2nd list.  Can you put that 'Where' in the first 'ToList()', or query everything you need in the first query?

``` ....ThenByDescending(i => i.id2).Select(i => new { i.TableXX.remaining, i.dueDate, i.OtherInterestingField, i.Field2 }).ToList();```

Comment: I can try to see if that helps, but I wouldn't be able to use it as my solution because this is building out a viewmodel that is very complex/convoluted. I call the parent items with all the data I need, and then use it in different sections of the view to get different data. For instance, in my example the Where(a=>a.Remaining > 0) is getting a list of those that have that Remaining > 0 but other parts of the view need the parent items filtered by another field.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging EF queries it helps to look at the whole execution as a whole, and run in conjunction with an application debugger. Repeated queries appearing like that are trademark of lazy load calls. With MVC applications this is commonly triggered by the serializer where entities are being sent to the client. (Rather than projected view models)

Without seeing the real code and what queries are being run, using the following example:

```
db.TableParent.Where(li => li.itemID == 16 && li.TableChild.TableXX != null && li.TableChild.companyId == company.id).ToList();
```

If the MVC controller in question is returning this "Parents" collection back to the view, the serializer is going to iterate over each parent, see the TableChild reference (along with any other references for children, grandchildren, etc. etc.) and when it touches those properties, if the DbContext has not already resolved them, the references will be lazy loaded one at a time.

The simple solution in this case would be to add an `.Include(x => x.TableChild)` to the query before the `.Where()` clause.  Long term it would be beneficial to look at sending view models rather than entities to avoid unexpected surprises like this.

Update: `GroupBy` does not pass through `Include` expressions in EF. You either need to perform the `GroupBy` in memory (expensive) or use the `GroupBy` to identify the IDs of the parents, then load the parents with their eager-loaded relationships. Alternatively if you can project your ViewModels into the query expression, you should be able to compose the view models without eager loading the relationships.

Example 1: Get IDs, then eager load:

```
List<int> currentTableParentItemIds = db.TableParent
    .Where(i => i.id == givenId)
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.id1, i.id2})
    .SelectMany(location => location
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.order)
        .Take(1))
    .Select(i => i.id) // Assuming this gives you the ID of the records you want.
    .ToList();

List<TableParentItem> currentTableParentItems = db.TableParent
    .Include(i => i.TableChild)
    .Include(i => i.TableXX)
    .Where(i => currentParentItemIds.Contains(i.id))
    .OrderBy(i => i.StartDate)
    .ThenByDescending(i => i.id2)
    .ToList();
```

The first query performs the group by to find the appropriate row IDs. The second does our full eager load and sorting to get the entities and their relatives.

Example 2: If this loading is to populate a view model then you would be better off removing the eager load `Includes` and project your view models directly in the query expression using `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo`. This may be a bit of a re-factor if you use factory methods or such to populate the view models since those won't project through EF to SQL.

```
List<ParentItemViewModel> currentTableParentItems = db.TableParent
    .Where(i => i.id == givenId)
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.id1, i.id2})
    .SelectMany(location => location
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.order)
        .Take(1))
    .Select(i => new ParentItemViewModel
    {
       id = i.Id,
       ChildName = i.TableChild.Name, // etc. Use whatever related tables needed. No need to eager load.
       // ...
    }).ToList();
```

The advantage of this approach is that it generates the most optimal SQL. Instead of passing back all parent columns, and all related object columns, the SQL generated by this expression will only return back what is needed to populate the view model. There is no risk of lazy load hits either so long as you don't embed any entities within the view model. (I.e. `Child = i.TableChild` = bad)

If the code to return the entities is isolated in something like a repository and returns something like `IEnumerable<ParentTable>` then to adopt optimizations like example 2 can be facilitated by adopting a return type of `IQueryable<ParentTable>` to allow consumers to refine the EF queries to project their specific needs. Otherwise, option #1 should get you there.

Comment: So I have a ViewModel builder function in my controller. All the code in my question is from that builder function. At the beginning of the builder I have the currentTableParentItems variable filled with the Include & ToList on it.

Later in the ViewModel builder, I use this variable to build out a result that only accesses children that were included with the Include previously.

I was expecting that this would resolve all of the parent and children items so that I can call them freely later without lazy loading, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue now. Your updated query has `a GroupBy`. `Include` does not get respected by `GroupBy` expressions. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572328/linq-when-using-groupby-include-is-not-working) Probably the best option would be to perform 2 queries, one without includes to determine the ParentIDs to load, and the second pass with the Include to load parents by those specific IDs. I will update my answer with an example.