# Eager loading is not retrieving related records with the first query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I have this EF query:

```
IQueryable<Repositories.Activo> activos = db.Activo.Include(a => a.ValorCampo)
                            .Where(a1 => a1.Carga.ClienteId == ClienteID && !hiddenWorkflow.Any(e => e.EstadoId == a1.EstadoId));
```

Where ValorCampo is a child table.

Well.... then, later in the program, I have this:

```
        var dashboard = activos.GroupBy(a => a.Localidad);

        foreach (var activo in dashboard.Skip(model.start).Take(model.length))
        {
            foreach(var campo in campos)
            {
                var totalEstado = activo.Where(a => a.ValorCampo.Any(vc => vc.ValorCampoCaracter == vc.Campo.CampoDashboard && vc.Campo.CampoDashboard == campo.CampoDashboard)).Count();

            }
        }
```

well, by adding "Include" to the query, I thought the actual executed query will include "ValorCampo" table, but that was not true. Or, doesn't it work when grouping? I don't think so.

The query to the related table is run for every iteration in the foreach loop. That is inefficient. I need the related information data to be loaded into memory with the first query.

How can I do it?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: I don's see the "eager" part.... For eager you need to call ToList for example to force the query to be executed... So maybe do something like var dashboard = activos.ToList().GroupBy(a => a.Localidad);

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro They are iterating the query in a `foreach` which will materialize the query.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro dashboard.Skip(model.start).Take(model.length) call is executing the query. No need to call ToList nor something like that.

Comment: FALSE:  Take and Skip would translate to SQL as well. The only part that is actually materializing your query could be the foreach or the call to "Count()"... So NO skip and take are NOT materializing functions...

Comment: @juharr that is also false... because this is just an iqueryable he could end up doing many queries against the database... He needs to EAGERLY materialize the query.  IEnumerable could very well be using YIELD which means there could be MANY queries being executed.

Comment: Very simple fireup SQL Profiler... and see how many queries are being performed,... This  query is using deferred execution...

Comment: What is `a.Localidad`? Does it point to a parent entity?

Comment: in EF 6.2 you cannot call Skip and Take on a query that has not been ordered.... Are you sure you stated the correction version of EF?

Answer (score -1):

According to this question in Stackoverflow the problem is the GroupBy.

Here is the same issue explained: [GrouBy and Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572328/linq-when-using-groupby-include-is-not-working)

There are two work arounds in the question one is to use ToList as described here and the other is to place the Include after the GroupBy.

Try something like this:

```
var dashboard = activos.ToList().GroupBy(a => a.Localidad);
```

Notice how I called ToList() to materialize the query....

To clarify GroupBy uses deferred execution which means it won't materialize the query.... Also Skip and Take use deferred execution which will also NOT materialize the query:

Here is some documentataion from Microsoft:

[GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)

[Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8)

[Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8)

All of them use deferred execution.

So you need to call ToList, FirstOrDefault, Single... etc one of the methods that materializes the query.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210908/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-alfaro-eager-loading-is-not-retrieving-related).